# PHP memory leak in recursive function when using ==

Tags: php, recursion, memory-leaks

I've got a strange problem here: the function I'm going to paste you causes a memory leak and so makes the server crash.

The strange thing is that if I change every `==` to `===` this memory leak does not occur.

```
private function controllaPrerequisitiPerEliminazioneAbilita( $pgid, $id_abilita, $lista_ab, $params = array() )
{
    global $PREREQUISITO_TUTTE_ABILITA;
    global $PREREQUISITO_F_TERRA_T_SCELTO;
    global $PREREQUISITO_5_SUPPORTO_BASE;
    global $PREREQUISITO_3_CONTROLLER;
    global $PREREQUISITO_4_SPORTIVO;
    global $ID_ABILITA_F_TERRA;
    global $ID_ABILITA_T_SCELTO;

    $query_ab = "SELECT * FROM abilita WHERE id_abilita = :id";
    $abilita  = $this->db->doQuery( $query_ab, array( ":id" => $id_abilita ), False );
    $abilita  = $abilita[0];

    $ab_prereq  = array_filter( $lista_ab, "Utils::filtraAbilitaSenzaPrerequisito" );

    $new_params = array();

    if( count( $ab_prereq ) > 0 )
    {
        $qta_sportivo = count( array_filter( $lista_ab, "Utils::filtraAbilitaSportivo" ) );
        $qta_sup_base = count( array_filter( $lista_ab, "Utils::filtraAbilitaSupportoBase" ) );
        $qta_controll = count( array_filter( $lista_ab, "Utils::filtraAbilitaController" ) );

        foreach( $ab_prereq as $i => $ap )
        {
            if (
                $ap["prerequisito_abilita"] == $id_abilita
                || $ap["prerequisito_abilita"] == $PREREQUISITO_TUTTE_ABILITA && $abilita["classi_id_classe"] == $ap["classi_id_classe"]
                || (
                    $ap["prerequisito_abilita"] == $PREREQUISITO_F_TERRA_T_SCELTO
                    && (
                        $id_abilita == $ID_ABILITA_F_TERRA
                        || $id_abilita == $ID_ABILITA_T_SCELTO
                    )
                )
                || $ap["prerequisito_abilita"] == $PREREQUISITO_5_SUPPORTO_BASE && $qta_sup_base < 5
                || $ap["prerequisito_abilita"] == $PREREQUISITO_4_SPORTIVO && $qta_sportivo < 4
                || $ap["prerequisito_abilita"] == $PREREQUISITO_3_CONTROLLER && $qta_controll < 3
            )
            {
                $new_params[] = $ap["id_abilita"];
                //removing this element from the array we will pass in the recursion
                Utils::rimuoviElementoArrayMultidimensionale( $lista_ab, "id_abilita", $ap["id_abilita"] );
            }
        }
    }

    if( count( $new_params ) > 0 )
    {
        foreach( $new_params as $p )
            $params = $this->controllaPrerequisitiPerEliminazioneAbilita( $pgid, $p, $lista_ab, $params );
    }

    return array_merge( $new_params, $params );
}
```

I really can't understand why is that. Can you please give me a hand here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you define "memory leak"? In what sense? How did it manifest? Are you sure that changing to strict comparison simply didn't result in less validated if-statements, resulting in your code actually doing less work and got a smaller result set?

Comment: Changing to `===` may mean that things aren't matching when they should, so you add fewer elements to `$new_params`. Or maybe using `==` was causing unintended matches, so `$new_params` was getting too big.

Comment: @magnus  The "memory leak" manifests through the crash of the XAMPP software that I'm using to run apache on windows. Barmar unfortunately I'm not able to print what goes on in $new_params since XAMPP crashes without allowing any printing. Thank you both for the answers!

Comment: Have you checked that it isn't because of what both me and Barmar pointed out?

Comment: I solved the mistery! The problem was in the function `Utils::rimuoviElementoArrayMultidimensionale` where I was supposed to remove the found id from the analyzed array so that in the following recursion it wouldn't have appeared causing infinite loops. It wasn't working because I had to pass the **pointer** of my array and not an actual array value. I hope I've been clear. Let me know!